# Why does MongoDB.Bson.BsonExtensionMethods.ToBson return bytes array instead of string?

Tags: vb.net, mongodb

And how does we convert bytes array into string?

I did:

```
 Dim queryPlaces = Query.WithinRectangle("LongitudeLatitude", (Longitude - eachStepLongitude), (Latitude - minimumBlock), (Longitude + eachStepLongitude), (Latitude + minimumBlock))
                    LogEvents(queryPlaces.ToBson.ToString)
```

This is for the mongdob driver for vb.net language.

I was surprised to find out that queryPlaces.ToBson returns bytes instead of string. Also ToBson.ToString simply return this useless string:

```
System.Byte[]
```

Comment: If you want a readable string, why not use `ToJSON` instead?  The "B" in BSON stands for "binary", hence what you see ...

Comment: Ah. Please turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a readable string, it's easier to use `ToJSON` instead.  `ToBSON` returns [BSON aka binary JSON](http://bsonspec.org/).